# Google maps doesn't show correctly when using jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to stuff a map (using v3 of the API) into a jQuery tab . I don't understand why i only see a little square of the map at the top left and the rest of the map is grey. This is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var map;
var layer;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.35300524537724, -82.31857926757817),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'sex',
      from: "1Cr2ObveEaSINhSVx1D9rZQN06o5aRxxcf8lFE6Y"

    },
    map: map

  });

}


function filterData {
var filter = [];
var stores = document.getElementsByName('store');

foe = stores[i]; i++) {
  if (store.checr (var i = 0, store; storked) {
    filter.push('\'' + store.value + '\''); 
 }
}

 if (filter.length) {
if (!layer.getMap()) {
  layer.setMap(map);

}
layer.setOptions({
  query: {
    select: 'sex',
    from: "1Cr2ObveEaSINhSVx1D9rZQN06o5aRxxcf8lFE6Y",
     where: '\'sex\' IN (' + filter.join(',') + ')'
  }
});

} else {
  layer.setMap(null);
 }
}

</script>

<div id="tabs-5">

<div id="map_canvas"></div>


</div>
  $(document).ready(function() { initialize(); });
```

I have looked same kind of problem at stackoverflow and try to solved from that answer. But my problem is not solved.  Please tell me where is the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with Google Maps API v3 + jQuery UI Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs)

Comment: What answers on StackOverflow did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Does the map api work outside of the jquery ui tab?

Comment: I don't see any code to trigger the resize event on the map when the tab is shown.

Comment: This is the link of my site http://zaarlyproject.netii.net/page1.html and map is in tab 5(lening).

Comment: @Archangel33 it is working good outside of the jquery ui tab

Comment: When i zoom in the browser then it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

You Might want to try adding this meta tag to your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I have a feeling that this is an issue dealing with your viewport not being setup correctly. 
Here is a link to a question that may help you with this issue. [Viewport meta Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397748)