# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Menu Parent Clickable on Mobile?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

So on the project I am on, I wanted the parent items of my navigation to be clickable, along with the dropdown appearing on :hover.

I found this jquery script and it worked great for that:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    if($(window).width()>992){
        $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

        });

        $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
            location.href = this.href;
        });

    }
});
</script>
```

However two problems arose with this:

1. When the viewport is greater than 992px and I resize the browser <992px the hover effect retains even though I would like the dropdown to appear when active at less than 992px. Is there a way to detect the resizing of the viewport to fix this?
2. When the viewport is less than 992px the parent items no longer work. Is there a way to possibly make the parent item clickable on a double click? I'd like it this way because people on mobile/tablet can tap once for dropdown and twice for the parent item.

This is my first stackoverflow posting and I would really appreciate any help anyone has to offer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the viewport is greater than 992px and I resize the browser
>   <992px the hover effect retains even though I would like the dropdown
>   to appear when active at less than 992px. Is there a way to detect the
>   resizing of the viewport to fix this?

**Ans** - Use `$(window).resize` event to capture browser `resize`

Ex:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
     if($(this).width()>992){
          //do relative stuffs here
     }
     else{
          //do relative stuffs here
     }
});
```

> When the viewport is less than 992px the parent items no longer work.
>   Is there a way to possibly make the parent item clickable on a double
>   click? I'd like it this way because people on mobile/tablet can tap
>   once for dropdown and twice for the parent item.

**Ans** - Capture `doubleclick` using <kbd>**[`dblclick`](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)**</kbd> event handler of `jquery`

Ex:

```
$('yourelementidorclass').dblclick(function(){
    //Do necessary stuffs here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However I'm not really savvy with Jquery :( Do you mind if I ask how I could implement this? Thank you

Comment: Well I can give you a clear picture if you try to create a demo of your problem in **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kaitlinj/72snk79f/2/ does this help? sorry this if this doesnt this is my first time using jsfiddle

Comment: thanks! this works for me :) however on mobile (tested with iphone6) does not work. would this solution work for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560653/jquery-on-double-click-events-mobile

Comment: Yes! `iPhone` you need to be more careful on attaching events as some are different for `iPhone` like instead of `click` you may have to write `touch` event..