# dblclick doesn't work on touch devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, touch

What would be the best way to have `dblclick` works on touch devices and PC browsers

Below code works perfectly fine with mouse double click but when tried on android touch device , doesn't work. What should I do differently? Very new to this

```
$(document).on("dblclick","#table_discrepancy tr", function() {

 var orderno = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
 var workorderno = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();

    server('/get_customer_info/' + orderno, function(result){

     var cus_name = result.name.replace(/^[\s]+/, '');
     cus_name = cus_name.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
     var phone_no = result.phoneno.replace(/^[\s]+/, '');
     var email = result.email.replace(/^[\s]+/, '');

          $('#customer_info_modal').modal('show');

          $('#orderno_modal').html('Order# : ' + orderno);
          $('#workorderno_modal').html('Work Order# : ' + workorderno);
          $('#customer_name_modal').html('Name : ' + cus_name);
          $('#customer_phoneno_modal').html('Phone#: ' + phone_no);
          $('#customer_email_modal').html('Email: ' + email);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile, I would use a mobile specific event such as taphold instead of double click as it will probably give a more native feeling user experience.

You can use jQuery mobile to provide mobile specific events:
http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: Thank you, tried to use that but as of long pages need to scroll down in device , during spelldown that trigger that `TAPHOLD` , so decided to use double click...

Comment: This is a bit hacky but you could try some of these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560653/jquery-on-double-click-event-dblclick-for-mobile

There is one that stops the user from scaling which interferes with the double click event that might work, but might also be annoying for users.

Answer (score 0):

**Using only JavaScript**

You can use "touchstart" event for a single touch,
but with calculating the time when he should click again

I used 400 (0.4s) as it's the longer duration between two touches
It's only an estimate, but it's still a reasonable time

```
let expired

let doubleClick = function () {
    console.log('double click')
}

let doubleTouch = function (e) {
    if (e.touches.length === 1) {
        if (!expired) {
            expired = e.timeStamp + 400
        } else if (e.timeStamp <= expired) {
            // remove the default of this event ( Zoom )
            e.preventDefault()
            doubleClick()
            // then reset the variable for other "double Touches" event
            expired = null
        } else {
            // if the second touch was expired, make it as it's the first
            expired = e.timeStamp + 400
        }
    }
}

let element = document.getElementById('btn')
element.addEventListener('touchstart', doubleTouch)
element.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick)
```

**In case of this error :**
*Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.*

event.preventDefault( ) not working if element = "document" or "document.body"
So the solution of that, you should have a full page div container :

```
let element = document.getElementById('container')
element.style.minWidth = '100vw'
element.style.minHeight = '100vh'
document.body.style.margin = '0px'
element.addEventListener('touchstart', elementTouch)
element.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself like this:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
    // time of current press
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime()
    // time between presses
    const tapLength = currentTime - this.lastTap

    if (tapLength < 500 && tapLength > 0) {
        // if double click
        e.preventDefault()
        this.avatarInput.click()
    } else {
        // if single click
        this.isPinching = false
    }
    // remember the time of the last touch
    this.lastTap = currentTime
})
```