# Angular 4 dblclick event not working in mobile view

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using double click functionality in my code. It's working fine in desktop view but the problem is that when I switch to mobile/tablet view double tap doesn't work.

Here's my code sample

**HTML:**

```
<a (dblclick)="viewRecord(item.id)">View Record Details</a>
```

**Component:**

```
viewRecord(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['course/view/', id]);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because, there is no `dblclick` event registered for mobile devices.

But there is a work around for this. It is kind of a hack. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560653/jquery-on-double-click-event-dblclick-for-mobile)

Instead of listening `dblclick` you can listen for normal `click` event

```
<a (click)="viewRecord(item.id)">View Record Details</a>
```

component file

```
private  touchTime = 0;

viewRecord(id) {

    if (this.touchtime == 0) {
        // set first click
        this.touchtime = new Date().getTime();
    } else {
        // compare first click to this click and see if they occurred within double click threshold
        if (((new Date().getTime()) - this.touchtime) < 800) {
            // double click occurred
             this.router.navigate(['course/view/', id]); 
            this.touchtime = 0;
        } else {
            // not a double click so set as a new first click
            this.touchtime = new Date().getTime();
        }
    }
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unpebs)

Comment: Thanks Amit. It can be use as a work around. But there should be a proper event handling for mobile devices on double tap.

Comment: Yes, that would be the great feature. But how often do we double click in a mobile? I guess none of the time. Probably that is why they have not added `dblclick`event.

Comment: If you using browser inspect mode to test your app, make sure the device selected is not a mobile device. I was pulling my hair out for over an hour.

Answer (score 1):

@Amit said it well

> That is because, there is no dblclick event registered for mobile devices.

Here is kind of the same solution, but the **RxJS** way:

**HTML:**

```
<a (dblclick)="click$.next(item.id)">View Record Details</a>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { buffer, debounceTime, map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  click$ = new Subject<number>();
  doubleClick$ = this.click$.pipe(
    buffer(this.click$.pipe(debounceTime(250))),
    map(list => ({ length: list.length, id: list[list.length - 1] })),
    filter(item => item.length === 2),
    map(item => item.id)
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doubleClick$.subscribe((id) => this.viewRecord(id));
  }

  viewRecord(id) {
    this.router.navigate(['course/view/', id]);
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-rxjs-dbl-click)

Comment: it's still a recurring problem. the RXJS way also helps.
just wanted to point that you meant (click) in your html rather than (dblclick) since it's the actual problem. am i right ?

`<a (click)="click$.next(item.id)">View Record Details</a>`