# javascript innertext of textarea doesn't reset realoading page

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have the following code that works perfectly when I load the page

it allows to **double click a P and make it editable with textarea** and revert it back to P when clicking the Save button

Double clicking the "*some lorem ipsum*" string will switch the P to a texarea which the content is taken from the P content so it will display "*some lorem ipsum*"

You make some edit , let say you delete the "*some lorem ipsum*" and you now write "*new content edited*",

when you click Save it turns back to showing the P which new content is now "*new content edited*"

**The issue that I'm experiencing is that if I click the reload button in Firefox**,

the P goes back to the original content "*some lorem ipsum*"

but if I doubleclick the "*some lorem ipsum*" string, the textarea text IS NOT PICKED from the P

instead it shows the previous "*new content edited*"

Am I forgetting something? Thank you for hinting

```js
var noteP = document.getElementById("noteP");
var noteTA = document.getElementById("noteTA");
var noteDD = document.getElementById("noteDD");
var noteED = document.getElementById("noteED");

var TestoOriginale = "";
var TestoAttuale = "";

noteED.style.display = "none";

noteP.ondblclick = function LoadText() {
  TestoOriginale = noteP.innerText;  // load the P text
  noteTA.innerText = TestoOriginale; // -THE ERROR IS HERE- write the P text into the textarea
  noteDD.style.display = "none"; // hide P DIV
  noteED.style.display = "block"; // show text area DIV
}


function UpdateText() {
  TestoAttuale = noteTA.value; // get current textarea text
  noteP.innerText = TestoAttuale; // write it into P
  noteDD.style.display = "block";
  noteED.style.display = "none";

}


document.getElementById("salvaBT").onclick = function AJAXPost(NoteUpdateForm) {

  UpdateText();

  /**
  more code later
  **/
}
```

```html
<div id="noteDD">
  <p id="noteP">some lorem ipsum</span>.</p>
</div>

<div id="noteED">
  <form action="./note-update.php" method="post" id="NoteUpdateForm">
    <textarea id="noteTA" name="NoteUpdateText" form="NoteUpdateForm" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>
  </form>
  <input type="button" value="Cancel"><input type="button" id="salvaBT" value="Save" onclick="javascript:AJAXPost(this);">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it ... For the initial value on the textarea you're taking the text inside the `<p>` right ? You're telling that even after a refresh you still get the edited text ?

Comment: @Seba99 the issue has been fixed, but there is the code snippet to check it in action. On a real page, after a reload, the textarea was showing the older edited content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, after the event you want to update textarea value after saving the changes.

You need to pass `value` to `textarea` to save the modification.

**instead of doing**

`noteTA.innerText = TestoOriginale;`

**do:**

`noteTA.value = TestoOriginale;`

When you use `innerText` you put text inside the `<textarea>` HTML selector instead of puting it into the textarea `value` attribute.

Comment: OUCH! you are right I was correctly using `.value` in one line and not in the other. Though I don't understand why with a page reload it keeps the old value (?!?)

Comment: I am happy that I could help :) Have a great code time!

Comment: P.S. do you know how to make the double click to work on a smartphone? Double click makes the zoom instead to open the textarea

Comment: It is this that makes really easy the trick --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40327468/3446280, no need of additional javascript, the page works as it is