# Why double click is not working on Iphones

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, double-click

I have a simple video player I would like to add double click events in my button, but unfortunately, it's not working in my iPhone but works perfectly in android

Here is my html

```
   <div id="skip_right" class='btn10sec_next skip_button'>

                </div>
```

and here is my js

```
$(".btn10sec_back").on("dblclick", function(){

        $("#videoplayer")[0].currentTime -=10;

      });
```

What do I need to do to so solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to differentiate single click event and double click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event)

Comment: why is my qn duplicate? @aymericbeaumet two different questions,

Comment: Within `dblclick` what happens on the iPhone when you add some kind of visual clue like a basic javascript `alert`?

Comment: @user9964622 Are you getting single click events? People seem to be coming with workaround on mobile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560653/jquery-on-double-click-event-dblclick-for-mobile