# Jquery double click not working for a dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I am working on a Cordova app using jquery. I want to hide a div when it is double clicked. I get an alert using the single click code below

```
$(document).on('click', '#dynamicDiv', function() {
   alert("click");
});
```

But I do not get a response with the double click code

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '#dynamicDiv', function() {
    alert("double click");
});
```

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/p7vhtuaj/) for me.

Comment: @hev1 It doesn't work if you also have a `click` handler. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uzL28s4t/

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether the DIV is dynamic. If you have a click and double click handler, only the click handler runs. The same problem happens without event delegation: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uzL28s4t/4/

Comment: @hev1 I'm confused. I see that the double click is working for you, but for me, when the div is dynamically created it does not work.  The puzzling part is that if I change it to a single click it works. Thats why I was wondering if it is different when div is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

dblclick is for mouse event desktop, may be you can refer to this answer [jQuery on 'double click' event (dblclick for mobile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560653/jquery-on-double-click-event-dblclick-for-mobile)