# dbClick no work for mobile device ? Angular 9 . How to fix?

Tags: javascript, angular

*dblclick* doesn't work for mobile? I don't know how to fix this and also don't know why no work?

```
            <div *ngFor="let singleObj of test;"
                (dblclick)="countDownTimer(set)">
            </div>


  countDownTimer(set, index) {
    this.showNote = true;
    if (this.countingWhile) return;
    this.countDown = this.trainingModalFromDialyGoal
      .getCounter(this.tick)
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (set.reps > 1) {
          this.countingWhile = true;
        }
        set.reps--

        if (set.reps < 1) {
          set.reps = 0;
          set.completed = true;
          this.playAudio();
          this.countingWhile = false;
          this.countDown.unsubscribe();
        }
        console.log('setssss', set.reps)
      }
      );
  }
```

I don't know why no work ?
What I need to change?
Can anyone help me with code please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560653/jquery-on-double-click-event-dblclick-for-mobile

Comment: I can't understand this is jquery...i need code help in angular :/

Comment: @str did you know how to fix ?

Comment: @str I see on angular but where to set code ?! :))