# Is there any way to make double-click events work in phones with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events

I realized my double click events don't work when I toggle the device toolbar.
I googled but I've seen only jQuery stuff and I have no idea about jQuery. How do I make this work?

```
stuff.addEventListener('dblclick', openOtherStuff)
```

I am trying to open a modal with this event. it perfectly works on pc, doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: I found this quite quickly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560653/jquery-on-double-click-event-dblclick-for-mobile - but I have never had to dblclick on my mobile and do not want to either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunately you can't listen for double tap event but you can measure the time difference between two single taps using touchstart event.

```js
let lastClick = 0;
const ele = document.querySelector('div');
ele.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // to disable browser default zoom on double tap
  let date = new Date();
  let time = date.getTime();
  const time_between_taps = 200; // 200ms
  if (time - lastClick < time_between_taps) {
    // do stuff
    console.log("done");
  }
  lastClick = time;
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>Touch</div>
```