# What is the best way to define the viewport of a webpage?

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta

I have a habit of looking at the code of many of the websites I visit and have seen the viewport defined in many different ways.

I have seen this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 " />
```

and this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
```

and this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 " />
```

I thought about combining all of them into something like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
```

But is there any benefit in that?
What is the best way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is initial scale, user-scalable, minimum-scale, maximum-scale attribute in meta tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)

Answer (score 5):

### width=device-width

> this means we are telling to the browser “my website adapts to your device width”

### Initial-scale

> This define scale the website, This parameter sets the initial zoom level, which means if **1 CSS pixel** is equal to **1 view port pixel**. This parameter help to when you changing orientation mode, or preventing a default zooming. without this parameter responsive site work.

### Maximum-scale

> Maximum-scale define maximum zoom. When you access website top priority is maximum-scale=1 won’t allow the user to zoom.

### Minimum-scale

> Minimum-scale define minimum zoom. this work same as above but define minimum scale. If you not define this its work without using this is useful when maximum scale is large and you want to set minimum scale that time you can use.

### User-scalable

> User-scalable assign **1.0** means website allow to zoom in or zoom out.
>
> But if you assign **User-scalable=no** its means website not allow to zoom in or zoom out.

Hope this help you!

Above is Sky Dreams answer on the following question: [What is initial scale, user-scalable, minimum-scale, maximum-scale attribute in meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777734/what-is-initial-scale-user-scalable-minimum-scale-maximum-scale-attribute-in)

Please review the following links:

Maximum-scale=1.0: http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-use-maximum-scale/

User-scalable=no: [To "user-scalable=no" or not to "user-scalable=no"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354435/to-user-scalable-no-or-not-to-user-scalable-no)

Minimal-ui: http://www.therightcode.net/use-minimal-ui-in-viewport-meta-tag/

Comment: thanks but if i do put in "ALL" of them like i did in the last example that is ok right i mean there is no disadvantage

Comment: If you have read the articles I mentioned you know the disadvantages