# How can I make my page not to be shown as zoomed in?

Tags: html, css

Good Everning,

I am currently trying to make my webpage responsive. When I show it in a 320px viewport width  it will show zoomed at the left. But if I zoom out, it looks like it should. I am using media queries. You can check it in the images. Please try to open in in a 320px vw. I can not paste all the code in the snippet, please check the whole code in:

https://github.com/diefonro/portfolio

[image]
[image]

```css
.text-title {
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    /* left: 250px; */
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }

  .pos-text {
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    /* left: 250px; */
    margin-top: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
  }

  .title {
    font-family: "Pangolin", sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    /* left: 250px; */
    color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  img.main-img {
    width: 430px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .home-cont{
    margin-left: 40%;
  }


  .about{
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  .about img {
    width: 280px;
    opacity: 80%;
    position: relative;
    /* left: 130px; */
    top: 170px;
  }

  .about-text{
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

  .about-text h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 200px;
    color: #065c2a;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgb(4, 82, 15);
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .about-text p {
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    /* left: 200px; */
    top: 250px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: rgb(75, 74, 74);
    margin-left: 30px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  .get-cv2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 250px;
    left: 120px;
    border: none;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 13px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.52);
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.404);
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    float: left;
    
    color: #065c2a;
    border: 1px solid #571e8d3b;
  }

  .services{
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    /* background-color: #28852d; */
  }

  .portfolio{
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .portfolio, .contact, footer{
    min-width: 1000px;
  }

  #footer-bcg{
    position: relative;
    top: 740px;
    width: 1100px;
    z-index: -3;
    opacity: 70%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Diefonro's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&family=Pangolin&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <a class="logo" href="#home">
          <img src="assets/logo/dfnr.png" alt="Diefonro logo" />
        </a>

        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="home-cont">
        <div class="main-text" id="home">
          <p class="text-title">Hi! This is</p>
          <h1 class="title gradient-title">DIEFONRO</h1>
          <p class="pos-text">Junior Front-End Developer</p>
          <a href="#contact"><button class="hire">HIRE ME</button></a>
          <a href="assets/files/Diefonro's CV.pdf" download="Diefonro's CV"
            ><button class="get-cv">GET CV</button></a
          >
          <img
            src="assets/img/Diefonro.png"
            alt="diefonro's ilustration"
            class="main-img"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about-sect-cont">
        <div id="about" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
        <div class="about">
          <div class="about-img">
            <img src="assets/img/dev1.png" alt="dev" class="dev-about" />
          </div>
          <div class="about-text">
            <h2>
              LET ME INTRODUCE <br />
              MYSELF
            </h2>
            <p>
              I am a passionate Front-End Junior Developer, currently located in
              Bogotá, Colombia, but willing to work for anyone in the world.
              <br />
              <br />

              I like music, I can play several instruments, I study medicine, I
              like art in every shape. And at least for me, the human body and
              developing are some of them.
            </p>
            <a href="assets/files/Diefonro's CV.pdf" download="Diefonro's CV"
              ><button class="get-cv2">GET CV</button></a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="services-sect-cont">
        <div id="services" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
        <div class="services">
          <div class="services-text-cont">
            <div class="services-text">
              <h2>Services</h2>
              <p>This are some of the services I can currently provide:</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="services-cards-cont">
            <div class="services-cards">
              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont1">
                  <img
                    src="assets/logo/629-6291879_the-image-is-of-a-greater-than-and.png"
                    alt="web-d.logo"
                  />
                  <h2>WEB DEVELOPMENT</h2>
                  <p>
                    For creating, building and maintaining your website based on
                    the World Wide Web.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont2">
                  <img src="assets/logo/5387361.png" />
                  <h2>WEB DESIGN</h2>
                  <p>
                    For gathering webpage layout, content production and graphic
                    design.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont3">
                  <img src="assets/logo/5998058.png" alt="web-d.logo" />
                  <h2>SEO OPTIMIZE</h2>
                  <p>
                    For improving the application to increase its visibility
                    when searched on search engines.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont4">
                  <img src="assets/logo/1991222.png" alt="web-d.logo" />
                  <h2>UX/UI DESIGN</h2>
                  <p>
                    For supporting users behaviour when interacting with the
                    product, besides to desinging aesthetic interfaces,
                    improving the flow of the application.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="technologies">
            <div class="services-text services-text2">
              <h2>Technologies</h2>
              <p>This are some of the technologies I can currently handle:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="techs-cont">
              <img src="assets/logo/1199118.png" alt="html5 logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/1199113.png" alt="css3 logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/1199124.png" alt="javascript logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/52234.png" alt="git logo" /> <br />
              <img
                id="gh-logo"
                src="assets/logo/4926624.png"
                alt="github logo"
              />
              <img
                id="bootstrap-logo"
                src="assets/logo/1348052.png"
                alt="bootsrap logo"
              />
              <img
                id="jq-logo"
                src="assets/logo/jQuery-logo.png"
                alt="jQuery-logo"
                title="Deepening..."
              />
              <img
                id="react-logo"
                src="assets/logo/1183672.png"
                alt="react.js logo"
                title="Deepening..."
              />
              <img src="assets/logo/688062.png" alt="photoshop logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/688064.png" alt="illustrator logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/688068.png" alt="after efects logo" />
              <img
                id="adobe-xd"
                src="assets/logo/688066.png"
                alt="adobe xd logo"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="portfolio" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
      <div class="portfolio">
        <div class="portfolio-text">
          <h2>Diefonro's Portfolio</h2>
          <p>Here are some of the creations I have developed:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-cont">
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Vegan-Store"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/vegan-st.png" alt="vegan store website" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
              <h2>Vegan Store Website</h2>
              <p>
                Template made specially for a regular Vegan Store (can be
                applied to any store).
                <br />
                <br />
                You can check the code on
                <a
                  class="gith-link"
                  target="_blank"
                  href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Vegan-Store"
                  >GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a href="https://diefonro.github.io/Vegan-Store" target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Google-Clone-Diefonro"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/google-cl.png" alt="google clone" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
              <h2>Google Clone</h2>
              <p>
                This is a google clone made completely from scratch by Diefonro.
                <br />
                <br />
                You can check the code on
                <a
                  class="gith-link"
                  target="_blank"
                  href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Google-Clone-Diefonro"
                  >GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/Google-Clone-Diefonro"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Budget-App"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/Budget-App.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
              <h2>Budget App</h2>
              <p>
                This is a budget application made with JavaScript to keep track
                of incomes and outcomes (It's in Spanish but you can easily
                understand).
                <br />
                <br />
                You can check the code on
                <a
                  class="gith-link"
                  target="_blank"
                  href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Budget-App"
                  >GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a href="https://diefonro.github.io/Budget-App" target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Calculator-JS"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/Calculator.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
              <h2>Calculator</h2>
              <p>
                This is a regular calculator application made on JavaScript, you
                can operate with a little more of the basic aritmethic
                operations.
                <br />
                <br />
                You can check the code on
                <a
                  class="gith-link"
                  target="_blank"
                  href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Calculator-JS"
                  >GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/Calculator-JS/"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Digital-Clock-JS"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/OCK.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
              <h2>Digital Clock</h2>
              <p>
                This is an application that shows a digital clock, besides to
                the current date, and a little animation.
                <br />
                <br />
                You can check the code on
                <a
                  class="gith-link"
                  target="_blank"
                  href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Digital-Clock-JS"
                  >GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/Digital-Clock-JS/"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/List-Of-Individuals"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/list-ind.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
              <h2>List Of Individuals</h2>
              <p>
                This is an application where you can add individuals to a list
                to keep track of them. There could be many examples.
                <br />
                <br />
                You can check the code on
                <a
                  class="gith-link"
                  target="_blank"
                  href="https://github.com/Diefonro/List-Of-Individuals"
                  >GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/List-Of-Individuals"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="contact" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
      <div class="contact">
        <div class="contact-cont">
          <h3>Contact me</h3>
          <form action="https://formsubmit.co/dafrprof@gmail.com" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
            <input
              type="hidden"
              name="_next"
              value="https://diefonro.github.io/portfolio/thankyou.html"
            />
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Your Email Address"
              required
            />
            <input type="text" name="_subject" placeholder="Subject" required />
            <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false" />
            <textarea
              minlength="10"
              name="textarea"
              id="message"
              cols="25"
              rows="10"
              placeholder="Message"
            ></textarea>

            <a href="thankyou.html">
              <button class="contact-btn">SEND</button></a
            >
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <a
        href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrés-fonseca-619385225/"
        target="_blank"
      >
        <img id="lil-footer" src="assets/logo/2111532.png" alt="linkedin logo"
      /></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/Diefonro" target="_blank">
        <img id="ghl-footer" src="assets/logo/4926624.png" alt="github logo" />
      </a>
      <small>Diefonro's Portfolio - Made by Diefonro - 2021</small>
    </footer>
    <img id="footer-bcg" src="assets/img/bcg-portfolio.png" alt="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i checked your code, you added `width` in `px` everywhere. When you stretch the screen to `320px` and your `width` is more than your screen size, it may out of of the document. Try to change `width` in `%`

Comment: I think your media query is wrong: `@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)`. Here `(min-width:320px)` means viewport width above 320px. You need to use max-width. Look at Example 24 on https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewport` meta tag is missing the `user-scaleable` setting. Therefore your website can be zoomed. The zoom state will be saved by the browser and restored once you revisit a website.

Try the following viewport meta tag to disable zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

```css
.text-title {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  /* left: 250px; */
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.pos-text {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  /* left: 250px; */
  margin-top: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
}

.title {
  font-family: "Pangolin", sans-serif;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  /* left: 250px; */
  color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

img.main-img {
  width: 430px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.home-cont {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.about {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.about img {
  width: 280px;
  opacity: 80%;
  position: relative;
  /* left: 130px; */
  top: 170px;
}

.about-text {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.about-text h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 200px;
  color: #065c2a;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgb(4, 82, 15);
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-text p {
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  /* left: 200px; */
  top: 250px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: rgb(75, 74, 74);
  margin-left: 30px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.get-cv2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  left: 120px;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.52);
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.404);
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  float: left;
  color: #065c2a;
  border: 1px solid #571e8d3b;
}

.services {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  /* background-color: #28852d; */
}

.portfolio {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.portfolio,
.contact,
footer {
  min-width: 1000px;
}

#footer-bcg {
  position: relative;
  top: 740px;
  width: 1100px;
  z-index: -3;
  opacity: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Diefonro's Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a class="logo" href="#home">
        <img src="assets/logo/dfnr.png" alt="Diefonro logo" />
      </a>

      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="home-cont">
      <div class="main-text" id="home">
        <p class="text-title">Hi! This is</p>
        <h1 class="title gradient-title">DIEFONRO</h1>
        <p class="pos-text">Junior Front-End Developer</p>
        <a href="#contact"><button class="hire">HIRE ME</button></a>
        <a href="assets/files/Diefonro's CV.pdf" download="Diefonro's CV"><button class="get-cv">GET CV</button></a
          >
          <img
            src="assets/img/Diefonro.png"
            alt="diefonro's ilustration"
            class="main-img"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="about-sect-cont">
        <div id="about" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
        <div class="about">
          <div class="about-img">
            <img src="assets/img/dev1.png" alt="dev" class="dev-about" />
          </div>
          <div class="about-text">
            <h2>
              LET ME INTRODUCE <br />
              MYSELF
            </h2>
            <p>
              I am a passionate Front-End Junior Developer, currently located in
              Bogotá, Colombia, but willing to work for anyone in the world.
              <br />
              <br />

              I like music, I can play several instruments, I study medicine, I
              like art in every shape. And at least for me, the human body and
              developing are some of them.
            </p>
            <a href="assets/files/Diefonro's CV.pdf" download="Diefonro's CV"
              ><button class="get-cv2">GET CV</button></a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="services-sect-cont">
        <div id="services" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
        <div class="services">
          <div class="services-text-cont">
            <div class="services-text">
              <h2>Services</h2>
              <p>This are some of the services I can currently provide:</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="services-cards-cont">
            <div class="services-cards">
              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont1">
                  <img
                    src="assets/logo/629-6291879_the-image-is-of-a-greater-than-and.png"
                    alt="web-d.logo"
                  />
                  <h2>WEB DEVELOPMENT</h2>
                  <p>
                    For creating, building and maintaining your website based on
                    the World Wide Web.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont2">
                  <img src="assets/logo/5387361.png" />
                  <h2>WEB DESIGN</h2>
                  <p>
                    For gathering webpage layout, content production and graphic
                    design.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont3">
                  <img src="assets/logo/5998058.png" alt="web-d.logo" />
                  <h2>SEO OPTIMIZE</h2>
                  <p>
                    For improving the application to increase its visibility
                    when searched on search engines.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="services-cont">
                <div class="cont4">
                  <img src="assets/logo/1991222.png" alt="web-d.logo" />
                  <h2>UX/UI DESIGN</h2>
                  <p>
                    For supporting users behaviour when interacting with the
                    product, besides to desinging aesthetic interfaces,
                    improving the flow of the application.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="technologies">
            <div class="services-text services-text2">
              <h2>Technologies</h2>
              <p>This are some of the technologies I can currently handle:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="techs-cont">
              <img src="assets/logo/1199118.png" alt="html5 logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/1199113.png" alt="css3 logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/1199124.png" alt="javascript logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/52234.png" alt="git logo" /> <br />
              <img
                id="gh-logo"
                src="assets/logo/4926624.png"
                alt="github logo"
              />
              <img
                id="bootstrap-logo"
                src="assets/logo/1348052.png"
                alt="bootsrap logo"
              />
              <img
                id="jq-logo"
                src="assets/logo/jQuery-logo.png"
                alt="jQuery-logo"
                title="Deepening..."
              />
              <img
                id="react-logo"
                src="assets/logo/1183672.png"
                alt="react.js logo"
                title="Deepening..."
              />
              <img src="assets/logo/688062.png" alt="photoshop logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/688064.png" alt="illustrator logo" />
              <img src="assets/logo/688068.png" alt="after efects logo" />
              <img
                id="adobe-xd"
                src="assets/logo/688066.png"
                alt="adobe xd logo"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="portfolio" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
      <div class="portfolio">
        <div class="portfolio-text">
          <h2>Diefonro's Portfolio</h2>
          <p>Here are some of the creations I have developed:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-cont">
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Vegan-Store"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/vegan-st.png" alt="vegan store website" />
            </a>
        <div class="portfolio-card-text">
          <h2>Vegan Store Website</h2>
          <p>
            Template made specially for a regular Vegan Store (can be applied to any store).
            <br />
            <br /> You can check the code on
            <a class="gith-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Vegan-Store">GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a href="https://diefonro.github.io/Vegan-Store" target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Google-Clone-Diefonro"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/google-cl.png" alt="google clone" />
            </a>
            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
              <h2>Google Clone</h2>
              <p>
                This is a google clone made completely from scratch by Diefonro.
                <br />
                <br /> You can check the code on
                <a class="gith-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Google-Clone-Diefonro">GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/Google-Clone-Diefonro"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Budget-App"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/Budget-App.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
                <div class="portfolio-card-text">
                  <h2>Budget App</h2>
                  <p>
                    This is a budget application made with JavaScript to keep track of incomes and outcomes (It's in Spanish but you can easily understand).
                    <br />
                    <br /> You can check the code on
                    <a class="gith-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Budget-App">GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a href="https://diefonro.github.io/Budget-App" target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Calculator-JS"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/Calculator.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
                    <div class="portfolio-card-text">
                      <h2>Calculator</h2>
                      <p>
                        This is a regular calculator application made on JavaScript, you can operate with a little more of the basic aritmethic operations.
                        <br />
                        <br /> You can check the code on
                        <a class="gith-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Calculator-JS">GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/Calculator-JS/"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/Digital-Clock-JS"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/OCK.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
                        <div class="portfolio-card-text">
                          <h2>Digital Clock</h2>
                          <p>
                            This is an application that shows a digital clock, besides to the current date, and a little animation.
                            <br />
                            <br /> You can check the code on
                            <a class="gith-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Diefonro/Digital-Clock-JS">GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/Digital-Clock-JS/"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-card">
            <a
              href="https://diefonro.github.io/List-Of-Individuals"
              target="_blank"
              class="vegan-st"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/list-ind.png" alt="budget app" />
            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-card-text">
                              <h2>List Of Individuals</h2>
                              <p>
                                This is an application where you can add individuals to a list to keep track of them. There could be many examples.
                                <br />
                                <br /> You can check the code on
                                <a class="gith-link" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Diefonro/List-Of-Individuals">GitHub</a
                ><br />
                <br />
                You can watch this page live
                <a
                  href="https://diefonro.github.io/List-Of-Individuals"
                  target="_blank"
                  >here</a
                >
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="contact" class="et">‎‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎‎</div>
      <div class="contact">
        <div class="contact-cont">
          <h3>Contact me</h3>
          <form action="https://formsubmit.co/dafrprof@gmail.com" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
            <input
              type="hidden"
              name="_next"
              value="https://diefonro.github.io/portfolio/thankyou.html"
            />
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Your Email Address"
              required
            />
            <input type="text" name="_subject" placeholder="Subject" required />
            <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false" />
            <textarea
              minlength="10"
              name="textarea"
              id="message"
              cols="25"
              rows="10"
              placeholder="Message"
            ></textarea>

            <a href="thankyou.html">
              <button class="contact-btn">SEND</button></a
            >
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <a
        href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrés-fonseca-619385225/"
        target="_blank"
      >
        <img id="lil-footer" src="assets/logo/2111532.png" alt="linkedin logo"
      /></a>
                                <a href="https://github.com/Diefonro" target="_blank">
                                  <img id="ghl-footer" src="assets/logo/4926624.png" alt="github logo" />
                                </a>
                                <small>Diefonro's Portfolio - Made by Diefonro - 2021</small>
                                </footer>
                                <img id="footer-bcg" src="assets/img/bcg-portfolio.png" alt="" />
</body>

</html>
```

What does `user-scaleable=no` do, and is using it *good*?
There are pro's and cons's, im using it in all my web projects, but judge for yourself:

- [To "user-scalable=no" or not to "user-scalable=no"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354435/to-user-scalable-no-or-not-to-user-scalable-no)
- https://dev.opera.com/articles/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/
- [https://web.dev/meta-viewport/#:~:text=The%20user%2Dscalable%3D%22no,contents%20of%20a%20web%20page](https://web.dev/meta-viewport/#:%7E:text=The%20user%2Dscalable%3D%22no,contents%20of%20a%20web%20page).

Comment: The main problem with `user-scalable=no` is the lighthouse score. I use it too when I want a PWA like an app and not like a webpage. But probably this property will disappear in the next years and replaced with `user-zoom`. I would also see a good alternative to force my view without any "zoom-warnings".