# css position fixed not working in chrome working on firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

position fixed not working in chrome but work on firefox how to solve this problem
i am using bootstrap in my design

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="factory.html">Factory</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="client.html">Clients</a>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="video.html">Video</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
     <img src="img/logo%20corner.png" class="center-block img-responsive aboutlogo">
    </div>



    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->


        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill fills" style="background-image:url('img//intro%203.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>P-DECO</h1>
                <p>YOUR   PARTNER   TO   THE   TOP </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

this html code must be fixed and i do it but it's not working in chrome or opera browser but it's work on fire fox perfect

css code:

```
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 65%;
}
.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;
    background-position:center ;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;background-origin: content-box;
    z-index: 1030;
    position: fixed;
}
```

click [here](http://p-decolb.com/aboutus.html) to see the website how it's appear on chrome and firefox

content code

```
<!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">    
        <div class="row vcenter">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
                <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
                <p>P-DECO is a fully integrated design and Wood  manufacturing firm that has developed over the years into a regional powerhouse mastering all facets of interior decorations in Wood and Steel With ISO certification . Our team is ready to assist from the initial conceptual design to the turnkey handover, bringing high quality services and delivering the highest standards.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 "><img src="img/iso.jpg"  class="center-block" id="isologo"></div>
        </div>

        <hr>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/558967750_442.jpg" class="center-block"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/modern-staircase-oak-wood-interior-design-ideas-home-decoration.jpg" class="center-block"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/slide3.jpg"  class="center-block"></div>    
</div>
        <hr>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><h1>WHO WE ARE </h1></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <p>WHO WE ARE 
P-DECO we believe that quality is the basis for success. Providing superior quality of products and timely services based on agreed budgets has made P-DECO a regional leader by adding great value to all projects, leaving our clients with a great level of satisfaction. Through training, synergy and motivation, our highly qualified team is fully dedicated to every assignment, allowing P-DECO to be amongst the best firms in the market. Having an esteemed reputation in the market is what we aim for, and thus with a little faith and confidence in our highly experienced team of engineers the job will be done.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>   
        <hr>

        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/MR.KL%20Faqra-wood%20work%204566333.jpg" class="center-block"  ></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/blue%20chair.jpg" class="center-block" ></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/Table%20support.jpg" class="center-block" ></div>    
</div>
        <hr>
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><h1>OUR VISION</h1></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <p>P-DECO is not about projects, it’s about People. We have an excellent team who share a passion for everything they do: from creative designers to expert project managers, production managers to quantity surveyors, supply chain leaders to health and safety specialists. Our talented people make the difference and systematically exceed expectations. We are proud to be recognized as Investors in People because our people invest so much of themselves in our clients and us. Our people love what they do and the way we do it. We believe our People set us apart giving us the edge to drive our business forward. And they can do the same for you and your business.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>   
               <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="center-block"  ></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/machine%202.jpg" class="center-block" ></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"><img src="img/machine%201.jpg" class="center-block"></div>    
</div>
        <hr>
```

Comment: I could not find any difference as your header works same in both browser.

Comment: i changed from 5 min like San say in here answer but it still have some problem some information in the content hide

Comment: Sharing a solution that I found. Take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679794/position-fixed-on-chrome-mobile-causing-element-to-move-on-scroll-up-down/#44680066) And a full explanation of "user-scalable=no" can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397748/whats-the-point-of-meta-viewport-user-scalable-no-in-the-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your header div with below code and check. If it works then you can remove inline style and place it in a class.

```
<header style="position: relative;"><div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="
">
        <!-- Indicators -->


        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill fills" style="background-image:url('img//intro%203.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>P-DECO</h1>
                <p>YOUR   PARTNER   TO   THE   TOP </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div></header>
```

Add below CSS

```
.carousel {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: No it didn't work you can chek the link put it above for the site the image header disappear on chrome when i put your code

Comment: it's work but this code hide some information below you can check the code above of content

Comment: Please try using z-index or top position for the hidden information.