# Position fixed on chrome mobile causing element to move on scroll up/down

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, scroll, css-position

I'm facing this strange issue that looks like a bug on Chrome mobile.

I have a div with position:fixed; aligned to the top right corner of the screen. On desktop, it works fine (it stays in place), in mobile, however, the div is moving when I scroll up or down. I made a video to explain it better:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCgN6ULkcMg

[image: scroll up]

*On scroll up works fine*

[image: scroll down]

*on scroll down, a piece of the div with position:fixed disappears outside the viewport*

I tried to isolate the problem on a fiddle, but couldn't reproduce it. So I encapsulated the entire website in a fiddle, and the issue stopped ocurring. I still didn't understand why.

Website isolated in a fiddle:
Removed*

Live website:
Removed*

Furthermore, I performed some tests on different devices, on the live website:

- Chrome mobile: **Bugs**
- Chrome desktop: **Works fine**
- Firefox mobile: **Works fine**
- Safari mobile: **Works fine**

Can someone explain me why Chrome Mobile have this issue, while the others don't?

My position:fixed div looks something like this:

```
div {
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:right;
}
```

*Removed the links because it's a client's website. The solution is in the answer below.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

For some reason, my Google Chrome on mobile required **`minimum-scale=1`** in the viewport `<meta/>`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1"/>
```

Comment: this worked, also the `position:sticky` worked for me as well (without this)

Comment: And to add to that: in my case it seemed like Chrome adjusted the scale to get some element into view that was sticking out _horizontally_. If you have an unexpected horizontal scrolling in addition to this issue, then that is probably the root cause of the weird vertical scroll as well.

Comment: @Thomas you should have posted it as an answer, this is a much better solution :)

Comment: but using minimum-scale=1 removes the responsiveness of the website, so how to correct that?

Comment: Chrome can force-enable `user-scalable`. and some users use that. So I decided to use JS with  `visualViewport` object with setInterval. (`visualViewport` has the resize event but with slow responsibility)

Comment: Worked just for Chromium/Chrome browsers. This one worked on all different browsers I tested:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51322362/1981328

Comment: Same problem using position fixed. Changed my meta tag to: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"/>` so i just added `minimum-scale=1` to the default of a create react app

Comment: this doesnt work for me in 2022 in chrome mobile

Answer (score 50):

The problem is with `meta tag` you must put there

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, 
                      width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
                      minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
                      user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

This is because *Chrome* browser change `height` of `viewport`.

Comment: Thanks, literally beat myself up for a few hours trying to figure it out. This one worked!

Comment: I only needed the height and width attributes.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Any maximum-scale value less than 3 fails accessibility. For me, including only width, initial-scale, and minimum-scale was sufficient to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your elements go out of the viewport, therefore Android Chrome auto scale the viewport. Decrease the elements which are bigger like the viewport.

Comment: Be descriptive when answering a question.

Comment: Following this answer, I used width: 100% and overflow: hidden in my container. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the element to start and stay at the top of the page try using

```
    #header {
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
    }
```

That just worked for me, at least in an earlier version of chrome desktop, when fixed was not behaving appropriately. Just be aware that relative positioned elements will not ignore sticky positioned elements like they do fixed.

Not sure if this will help but it's the answer I was searching for when I got to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to check if there is something hanging out your viewport, adjusting the viewport meta tag may not be needed.

If that sticky thing is still wobbling, or just to give the browser a little more time to breath, consider adding

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

This will help you, my friend :D
When using z-index too, make sure it's applied always, assuming z-index is no applied non-sticky.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was missing the following CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

When i added this CSS then all went well

Comment: The reason why this works is written in the previous response from Surjeet Bhadauriya.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was in a browser extension for mobile browsers(such as Kiwi). My fixed element briefly moved up and down when the address bar slide out of or into sight as you scroll up and down.

The solution turned out to be to use the "bottom" property to set the fixed location instead of "top." I didn't even know that existed before.