# Position:fixed div touch area shifts up while scrolling down on chrome mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

I have div with the id #sy-whatshelp for a floating chat head which has the property Position:fixed as I want it fixed on the bottom right corner of the viewport. The css for the div is

```
#sy-whatshelp {
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The issue is that in chrome mobile browser when scrolling down very fast, the touch area of the div shifts up even though visually the div stays in the correct position as defined by my css. How do I make the touch area of the div stick to the correct place too as defined by my css.

Here is a video link of the problem in chrome mobile dubugger connected to a pc using adb. You can see that the highlighted portion identifying the div goes up while scrolling down but visually its in the correct place.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaNDx.jpg

I have tried this solution with no avail
[Position fixed on chrome mobile causing element to move on scroll up/down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679794/position-fixed-on-chrome-mobile-causing-element-to-move-on-scroll-up-down)