# Prevent zooming using a touchscreen in a website (IE 11, Win 10)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a website created using jQuery Mobile. And I want to disable the zoom functionality or prevent the user from being able to zoom in using pinch zoom or tapping with 2 fingers simultaneously.

I was looking for an answer but I just can't find an answer that works.

I tried using the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Also tried:

```
body { -ms-content-zooming: none },
html { -ms-content-zooming: none },
.ui-page { -ms-content-zooming: none }
```

None of those solutions work.

Comment: check a bit similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397748/whats-the-point-of-meta-viewport-user-scalable-no-in-the-google-maps-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more research i finally found a solution to my problem. Not the most handsome one but it works for me.
 I had to add an additional Key to the Internet Explorer Registry`(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom`) to prevent any Zoom.
A full guide can be found **[HERE](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-disable-the-zoom-level-option-in-internet-explorer/)**

Comment: This approach is will only work on your _own_ computer. It will not have any effect on any other computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `user-scalable = no` instead of `user-scalable = 0`.

Comment: I have also tried this and unfortunately it doesnt work.