# W3C don't validate Viewport

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

[W3C don't validate my viewport meta tag](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fdidix13.com%2F) any idea why?

```
<title>DIDIx13</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /> 
<!-- Throws a warning "Consider avoiding viewport values that prevent users from resizing documents." -->
<meta name="keywords" content="DIDIx13" >
<meta name="description" content="I'm Darwin and welcome to my website" >
```

Comment: As the validator says `Consider avoiding viewport values that prevent users from resizing documents.` But IMHO you want that. People get enerved when on mobile it zooms the website.

Comment: @AjAX. [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) has a perfect example of viewport and my website should be responsive. Why would a validator so known recommend this?

Comment: `Responsive != Ability to zoom.` The validator is — not — only so known. It is the validator of the maker of the `HTML Protocol`. But inventing things does — not — always make you the best user of it.

Comment: W3C !== W3Schools. W3Schools is generally a load of old ####. At least it used to be.

Comment: @ggdx I know that and it's not useful to my question.

Comment: For me I always want the `App feeling` without the zoom. No high visitor site uses zoom in `viewports`.

Comment: That said, recommended is zooming on non-for-mobile-designed sites. You want to have big buttons and all that. Here W3C probably checks if you know what you are doing. Keep in mind.

Comment: Why downvotes? What can I improve?

Comment: @Didix The W3Schools example is **without** userscalable=no, hence in line with W3 recommendation. Besides, W3Schools is a great resource for developers, it just has too many cookies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### TL;DR

Remove `"user-scalable=no"` and now the validator is fully ok!

---

I've found out the purpose of `"user-scalable=no"`, thanks to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544312/8303093)

> Actually `"user-scalable=no"` prevents the user from zooming. And it allows the browser to gain 300ms per click.

300ms per click? That's pretty damn good! I should let `"user-scalable=no"`

But this is **no longer the case**, according to [efheng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910559/8303093).

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` is enough to remove 300ms delay.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention that any `-scale` property also triggers that warning

Therefore you should remove all of the following properties, if existent

- user-scalable
- initial-scale
- maximum-scale
- minimum-scale